How I can have vscode only type check a specific folder?
These settings appear to do nothing:
"python.analysis.exclude"
"python.analysis.include"

If I do this all files are still type checked:
"python.analysis.exclude": [
    "**"
],

I want to do this inclusively ie only type check a specific folder and nothing else. This seems to do nothing (all files are type checked):
"python.analysis.include": [
    "some-strict-code/**"
],

